# default coder for pojo object in apache beam

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io

As per apache beam documentation, I can find data type specific coders and also custom coders. It provides feasibility to create custom coders by registering with code registry. But I would like to know if there is any coder available for POJO/bean. For example,what is the coder for PCollection

Answer (score 3):

If your POJO is defined within your project, then take a look at [DefaultSchema](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.10.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/schemas/annotations/DefaultSchema.html). The example there does exactly what you want, registering a schema (which implicitly registers a coder) by inspecting JavaBean-compliant methods:

```
@DefaultSchema(JavaBeanSchema.class)
class MyClass {
  public String getFoo();
  void setFoo(String foo);
        ....
}
```

Note that coders are for *elements* of a collection, so there is no coder for PCollection. Rather, a PCollection can have a coder set, determining how individual elements are serialized and deserialized.

Comment: Thanks for this piece of information, I have a scenario here. Consider i have a PCollection<bean> (bean is the pojo class here) . when i tried to implement ParDo transformation on that PCollection, I am getting the coder error (The error is -  Unable to fetch the coder, use setcoder method ). As per apache beam documenation, there are specific coders for int, void, strng, avro. So I am wondering, what is the coder i need to implement in this scenario

Comment: If you have control over the definition of `bean` and you annotate with `@DefaultSchema(JavaBeanSchema.class)` and `bean` has no type parameters, then Beam should have enough information to infer a coder; the coder error you mention should go away. Otherwise, your options are to transform your object to a simpler type so that you end up with something like a PCollection<Map<String, String>> or to implement an explicit Coder subclass for your type and pass an instance of that coder class to `setCoder`.